# Emulator takes forever to shutdown!

Tags: android-emulator, shutdown

The title just says it all. My 3.3", Android 2.3.3 emulator (armeabi) boots averagely in 150 seconds on my Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit system, with 2 GB DDR3 memory. However, sometimes when I tried shutting down using the power button provided in the emulator. I am made to wait indefinitely!

This doesn't hurt much, for I usually just close the emulator just like closing a window. However, I somehow can't reconcile the fact and need to know reason(s) why, in spite of booting fairly fast, shutting down takes ages! Does shutting down consume more resources than booting?!